# Apache Forward Proxy (SSL between Client and Proxy)

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy

I've configured an Apache VirtualHost to act as an HTTP forward proxy, works great, but I would like the connection between the client and the proxy server to be encrypted.

Is that something Apache supports through any existing mods, if so which ones/have any instructions? or do I have to look at something like tunneling HTTP over HTTPS?

Answer (score 1):

It is a usual case, you have a proxy with SSL termination, the connection between the client and the proxy is SSL encrypted. At the proxy, the traffic is being decrypted and forwarded to the real server(s) on the local/trusted network. All can be done with the internal Apache mods, i.e. mod_ssl.